# Cannot import name 'preprocessing' from 'tensorflow.keras.experimental in tensor flow 2.4.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.experimental import preprocessing
```

When I run the code above. I get:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocessing' from
> 'tensorflow.keras.experimental".

Note, I am using TensorFlow 2.4.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing`?

Comment: It worked. Write that as an answer @Enzo, and I will accept it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the wrong import. Try changing

```py
from tensorflow.keras.experimental import preprocessing
```

to

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
```